# Appending an unordered list within a paragraph using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

For a client-side class, I am modifying an XHR-request/getElementById to be a jQuery-ajax-request/jQuery-document-manipulation.
It should display descriptions of one of 4 items from “Rob’s Rock & Roll Memorabilia”.
I am adding 3 paragraphs to an output div with the ID of “description”; description, price, and one or more url’s.
Adding the description text and price text within the open and close paragraph tags work fine.

***The question:
I am having issues adding the 2 or 3 url’s in a returned XML document as anchor-tag links each within a list item all within an unordered list that is within a paragraph.
The string displays in the console as I’m pretty sure it should, but when I inspect the page I get: 1) p-open tag, 2) p-close-tag, 3) the unordered list (multiple elements), 4) p-open-tag, and 5) p-close-tag.
I don’t understand how the description and price paragraphs were appended find, but the url paragraph added a close-paragraph tag before the unordered list I want to appedn and then added an open-paragraph tag after the ordered list I appended.

I found a question about dynamically adding 3 unordered lists with jQuery, but it was not yet answered.

My data:
A sample XML document being returned is:

```
  <item id="itemHat">
   <description>Michael Jackson's hat as worn in the "Billie Jean" video. Not    really rock memorabilia but it smells better than Slash's tophat.
   </description>
   <price>1699.99</price>
   <resources>
     <url>http://www.michaeljackson.com/</url>
     <url>http://music.yahoo.com/vid-2143030--Billie-Jean</url>
   </resources>
  </item>
```

This is the code that I am using is:

```
// Add description and price to description output area.
descriptionSring = "<p>Description: " + $(xml).find("description").text() + "</p>";
priceString = "<p>Price: " + $(xml).find("price").text() + "</p>";
$("#description").append(descriptionSring + priceString);
// Add URL's to description output area.
$(xml).find("resources").each( function(resoureceIndex, resourceValue) {
    urlString = "";
    $(this).find("url").each( function(urlIndex, urlValue) {
        urlString += "<li><a href='" + urlValue.textContent + "'>" + urlValue.textContent + "</a></li>";
    });
    $("#description").append("<p><ul>" + urlString + "</ul></p>");
    console.log(urlString);
});
```

Web Page Inspector (Chrome) shows:

```
  <div id="description">
    <p>Description: Michael Jackson's hat as worn in the "Billie Jean" video. Not   really rock memorabilia but it smells better than Slash's tophat.</p>
    <p>Price: 1699.99</p>
    <p></p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.michaeljackson.com/">http://www.michaeljackson.com/</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://music.yahoo.com/vid-2143030--Billie- Jean">http://music.yahoo.com/vid-2143030--Billie-Jean</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

The console shows that urlString is (which looks to me like it should work):
“

http://www.michaeljackson.com/'>http://www.michaeljackson.com/

http://music.yahoo.com/vid-2143030--Billie-Jean'>http://music.yahoo.com/vid-2143030--Billie-Jean

”

Comment: You can see the actual source code in chrome by pressing option+cmd+U  (ctrl+alt+U on Windows) - could you please post what it is showing there?

Comment: Good tip. I just copied&pasted from Brackets; which should be equivalent but may not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another method and it seems working.

HTML:

```
<p id="desc"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $p = $("<p></p>");
var lis = "<li>Test</li><li>Test 2</li>";
var $ul = $("<ul>" + lis + "</ul>");
var $final = $p.append($ul);

$("#desc").append($final);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetb/1qf83x1g/

Comment: Thanks @MehmetBaker! That worked great. I see now to break it down to each element or set of elements, then build it back up and finally assign it.  I gave you an up-vote, but I lack the site experience for you to see it.

Comment: You are welcome @MikeAusloos. Yes, voting requires reputation but you can accept the answer as the owner of the question. It should be located under the voting arrows as a checkmark.

Comment: Thanks again @MehmetBaker. I now have accepted the answer and the page is now rendered and styled as it should be.  Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you too @MikeAusloos. Happy coding!